# Hibernate Transaction Timeout - Exception Handling

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, transactions, jta

I set transaction timeout to 10 second. The transaction gets timed out.
Will it throw any exception ?
(In hibernate)

```
try {
 session.getTransaction.setTimeout(10);
 session.getTransaction().begin();
 session.persists(something);
 session.getTransaction().commit();
} catch(Transaction - Time - out Exception) {
 if it times out I want to come here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will throw RuntimeException.